# Node discovery (Kademlia) not working after upgrading chain from v2.0 -> v3.0

Tags: upgrade

I am experiencing some issues with node discovery after upgrading from substrate 2.0 to substrate 3.0

After upgrading our chain from using substrate 2.0 to substrate 3.0 (Upgrading the client & runtime with a forkless upgrade), the nodes fail to discover peers through Kademlia. mDNS is disabled (on purpose) and only bootnodes are being discovered.

If I the same build and create a new chainspec and chain starting from block Kademlia discovery is working as intended.

The version of libp2p used is 0.36.0.
I add –log sub-libp2p flag on the node and I can see in the logs that the substream is opened, the Kademlia discovery being invoked, but throws this error `Failed to get record: NotFound`

```
validator-1_1   | 2022-02-17 15:33:59.909 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker sub-libp2p: External API <= Message(12D3KooWEyoppNCUx8Yx66oV9fJnriXwCcXwDDUA2kj6vnc6iDEp, SetId(2))    
validator-1_1   | 2022-02-17 15:33:59.910 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker sub-libp2p: External API => Notification(PeerId("12D3KooWEyoppNCUx8Yx66oV9fJnriXwCcXwDDUA2kj6vnc6iDEp"), "/paritytech/grandpa/1", 150 bytes)    
validator-1_1   | 2022-02-17 15:33:59.910 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker sub-libp2p: Handler(PeerId("12D3KooWEyoppNCUx8Yx66oV9fJnriXwCcXwDDUA2kj6vnc6iDEp")) <= Sync notification    
validator-1_1   | 2022-02-17 15:33:59.926 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker sub-libp2p: Handler(ConnectionId(TaskId(0))) => Notification(12D3KooWEyoppNCUx8Yx66oV9fJnriXwCcXwDDUA2kj6vnc6iDEp, SetId(2), 150 bytes)    
...
validator-1_1   | 2022-02-18 08:20:58.033 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker sub-libp2p: Addresses of PeerId("12D3KooWEyoppNCUx8Yx66oV9fJnriXwCcXwDDUA2kj6vnc6iDEp"): ["/dns/validator-0/tcp/30333", "/dns/validator-0/tcp/30333", "/dns/validator-0/tcp/30333", "/dns/validator-0/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWEyoppNCUx8Yx66oV9fJnriXwCcXwDDUA2kj6vnc6iDEp"]    
...
2022-02-18 08:21:04.063 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker sub-libp2p: Libp2p => Failed to get record: NotFound { key: Key(b"h\xe9\xa0\xe3h\x17\x1e\xfc\xfds\xc0\x8c\x11\x8c\n\x9f\x03\xa6\xe5\xac\xa6\xd5{\x11\x83\x94\xeda\xc9\xa6P\xc9"), closest_peers: [PeerId("12D3KooWEyoppNCUx8Yx66oV9fJnriXwCcXwDDUA2kj6vnc6iDEp")] }    
validator-1_1   | 2022-02-18 08:21:04.063 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker sub-libp2p: Libp2p 
...
```

Are there any know issues in this area? Closest I could find was this, but the fix is already applied to our codebase.
https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/7985/files

I also tried to rotate the session keys in the validators, just in case there was an issue with old keys but nothing changed.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: Which substrate 3 version? A monthly tag, master or something else?

Comment: v3.0.0 tag from codebase

Comment: I think 3.0.0 tag was a while ago. I would recommend choosing the latest monthly tag or the last tagged polkadot version or master.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like some incompatibilities from the numerous libraries involved. Substrate 2.0 is very behind. I would rebuild your node starting from the latest node template to fix this.